# Run main in a project from EAR project

Tags: java, jboss, program-entry-point, ear

I am working on an EAR project for jboss eap 6.4, and I need to run some lines of code upon deployment of the project. I was trying to add to a project belonging to the EAR project, a java main class, and setting it on this project on the Run/Debug Settings. But it is not working.

So the question is, how can I run a main class, or a piece of code upon the EAR project deployment.

Thanks!!

Comment: where is the code ? Add it to here

Comment: The code is not the problem, for now im just trying to perform an output on the console. My problem is the configuration of a main class, or something to run when deploying for the first time the EAR project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end I created a class in my web project within the EAR project as follows:

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/")
public class RestApplication extends Application {

    public RestApplication(){
        /* Code to be executed upon deployment */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **run some lines of code upon deployment of the project** you can use the following options:

(1) Override `ServletContextListener` methods, `contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)` method will be invoked automatically during server start up. **This is the preferable approach.**

(2) Use the code inside Servlet `init`(), will be called during servlet initialization time

(3) Use a `static` initializer for your `main` class which will run your code during the class loading time of the Server container.

The preferred approach is Option(1), for which you can look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) for `ServletContextListener`